# regex filename of a unixpath without the first two digits

Tags: regex, path, filenames

I have filename in a unix-path starting with two digits ... how can i extract the name without the extension

`/this/is/my/path/to/the/file/01filename.ext` should be `filename`

I currently have `[^/]+(?=\.ext$)` so I get `01filename`, but how do I get rid of the first two digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a look-behind in front of what you already have, looking for two digits:

```
(?<=\d\d)[^/]+(?=.ext$)
```

This only works if you have exactly two digits! Unfortunately, in most regex engines it is not possible to use quantifiers like `*` or `+` in lookbehinds.

- `(?<=\d\d)` - checks for two digits before the match
- `[^/]+` - matches 1 or more characters, except `/`
- `(?=.ext$)` - checks for `.ext` behind the match

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
/\d\d(.*?).\w{3}$
```

Explanation :

`/\d\d` : slash followed by two digit

`(.*?)` : the capture

`.\w{3}` : a dot followed by three letters

`$` : end of string

It works for me on Expresso

Answer (score 0):

A more general regex:

```
(?:^|\/)[\d]+([^.]+)\.[\w.]+$
```

Explanation:

```
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
    ^                        the beginning of the string
   |                        OR
    \/                       '/'
  )                        end of grouping
  [\d]+                    any character of: digits (0-9) (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \1
  \.                       '.'
  [\w\.]+                  any character of: word characters (a-z, A-
                           Z, 0-9, _), '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, but with this version, the filename is not parsed correctly sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\d{2})[^/]+(?=.ext$)
```

Good Luck!